# Mongo $group array elements based on input array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My collection has following format -

```
{
 "title" : "Seasonal", 
 "state" : "Maharashtra",
 "fruits" : [ "banana", "orange", "jackfruit", "mango", "tamarind"]
} 
{
 "title" : "Seasonal", 
 "state" : "Karnataka",
 "fruits" : [ "banana", "avacado", "blackberry", "coconut", "grape"]
}
{
 "title" : "Alltime", 
 "state" : "Karnataka",
 "fruits" : [ "banana", "lemon", "pomegranate", "pineapple"]
}
```

And my query is like

```
db.fruits.aggregate([{"$match": {"state": "Karnataka", "fruits": {"$elemMatch": {"$in": ["banana","coconut"]}}}},{ $unwind : "$fruits" },{"$group" : {"_id" : "$fruits","count" : {"$sum":1}}}])
```

And getting Output as -

```
{ "_id" : "pineapple", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "lemon", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "grape", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "pomegranate", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "coconut", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "blackberry", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "avacado", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "banana", "count" : 2 }
```

Instead in return what I want is input fruit names with count of their occurance. i.e.

```
{ "_id" : "coconut", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "banana", "count" : 2 }
```

Will you please tell me, How to $group these array elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below aggregation. You are missing a `$match` stage after `$unwind`.

Initial match only filters document where there exists fruits array with at least one fruit from matching input fruits array.

Once you `$unwind` it unwinds all the fruits which also includes other fruits. So when you use second match you filter the fruits to only contain fruits matching from input fruits array.

```
db.fruits.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"state":"Karnataka","fruits":{"$elemMatch":{"$in":["banana","coconut"]}}}},
  {"$unwind":"$fruits"},
  {"$match":{"fruits":{"$in":["banana","coconut"]}}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$fruits","count":{"$sum":1}}}
])
```

Comment: Will you please help me with this. I want a counts of fruits containing banana, coconunt, [banana, coconut](no $elementMatch i.e $all) separately

Comment: Not sure I follow you. You want count of all fruits together ?

Comment: No no. I want to query array of array.. like ["banana, coconut, lemon"] , ["orange", "jackfruit"] returning array with counts opposite to $elementMatch

Comment: I see. You can write a or condition with each condition being  in criteria matching each array. Something like `{$or:[{$in:first set}, repeat for all sets]}`

Comment: But Using $or will give me count for only one array condition. I want it for all at once like above output.

Comment: No.Include all your conditions inside or. Something like `{$or:[{$in:first set}, {$in:second set]}`